What is the word for something being called something incorrectly, based on its appearance?
My example is a plate of food that looks like cookies, but are actually savory and tomato-basil flavored. Supposing that it's agreed that calling them "cookies" is incorrect (maybe debatable also), is there a word for incorrectly calling them cookies solely because they look like cookies?
I thought of the word misnomer, which could apply here. But that's just a general term and doesn't take appearance into consideration.
I also thought of malapropism, but that's more of a humorous misusage of a word, and doesn't really apply here.
I searched this wonderful site and ending up going down the rabbit hole of iconicity, but that's not what I'm looking for.
So I'm wondering if there's a word for calling something the wrong name based on how it looks?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Out of interest the items that Americans call "cookies" are called "biscuits" in British English (the items t

May be "misresemblance" as defined in wikitionary.

'Misrecognize is a verb that means to fail to recognize or identify something or someone correctly. It is derived from the prefix mis- and the verb recognize, and first appeared in the 1960s' (oed.com). So misidentify is a word too, but I would use mistook probably.

Your "first impression" is that they're cookies. But do you want a word for the act of mistaking/misidentifying them, or the practice of naming something after what it is not but may superficially resemble (there are questions here about misnomers; you could search).

@BoldBen - Also, British biscuits can be either sweet or savoury. Are cookies sweet by definition?

I have sometimes seen the word "misrecognition" used in the domain of OCR (Optical Character Recognition)

@KateBunting Yes; the word cookie only refers to the sweet kind.

I don't think there's a comon term specific to this. It's just a mistake. "I mistook those fritters for cookies."

Judging-a-book-by-its-cover.

@YosefBaskin That means assessing the quality of something based on superficial aspects. It has nothing to do with mistaking what something is.
